# Add class to a div via Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the div which is generated when page loads as below.

```
<div class="redactor_ redactor_editor"></div>
```

How can I add a class .example onto it via jquery like below?

```
<div class="redactor_ redactor_editor example"></div>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry but I think you need to take a basic tutorial about jQuery.

Comment: You haven't accepted any answer yet. Are you looking for replacing the previous class with a new class?

Comment: I'll try to create a working copy of my code on http://jsfiddle.net/ for everyone to see what is going on in my code...

Comment: Here is a copy of my working code. jsfiddle.net/bYSs3/4 The purpose of my question is to change the vertical scrollbar by adding a class .example that I believe to be added on the div with class .redactor_ redactor_editor

Answer (score 4):

Try [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) this,

```
$('.redactor_').addClass('example');
```

just select element using any selector

```
$(selector).addClass('example');
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/pZqNQ/1/)

Answer (score 2):

you can add class to element by using the  [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

syntex

```
.addClass( className )
```

> **className** One or more class names to be added to the class attribute of each matched element.

so now this is you want

```
$('.redactor_ redactor_editor').addClass('example');
```

Comment: does it work with the space in the class name after the first underscore sign? (redactor_ redactor_editor)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class regardless of what it was by using `.attr()` like this,

If the html is like this,

```
<div class="redactor_ redactor_editor"></div>
```

then the selector will be like the following,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.redactor_redactor_editor').attr('class', 'redactor_redactor_editor example');
});
```

Since your div tag's class name has a space after the underscore sign(i.e. redactor_ ) the following way must be applied to select the element.(`<div class="redactor_ redactor_editor"></div>`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div[class='redactor_ redactor_editor']").attr('class', 'redactor_ redactor_editor example');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<pre>
 $(window).load(function () { 
   $('.redactor_ redactor_editor').addClass('example');
 });
</pre>
```

reference :
[addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for adding a new css class to an element that already has a class then-

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pVySp/)

HTML-

```
<div class="one">example</div>​
```

CSS-

```
.one{color:red;}
.two{color:green}​
```

jQuery-

```
$(function(){
 $('.one').addClass('two');
});​
```

If you are looking for removing the old css class and add a new class-

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/hnuZ5/1/)

jQuery-

```
$(function() {
    $('.one').removeClass('one').addClass('two');
});​
```